# One table for all users or separate table for each user in MySQL 10M records db

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I am working on the website that could deal with 1000s of images for my clients. Say 20,000 files per user, circa 200 users (with hopes for 1000s soon).

- Images are represented by `vFile` (unique id) records in MySQL InnoDB database describing ownership and permissions, location in the folder tree, location of physical files on S3, size etc.
- Users can create, delete, reorder etc those `vFiles`.
- Each user can alter only `vFiles` he owns.

The database dilemma is:

- all the `vFile` records in one table or
- separate table for each user.

Second solution seems to have a few advantages:

- as queries will search for `vFiles` for one user only, second solution reduces load on the db.
- operations on `vFiles` (like renaming, deleting, reordering) will affect much smaller tables.

Your thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: why not you directly use S3 permission?

Answer (score 1):

The second solution does not seem to account for future changes to site’s features. For instance, what if at a later date you would like to allow users to share images, or allow for image pools with multiple users having different permission levels to a file? If you went with solution #2, adding those features would result in a lot of duplicate entries. In general, if you have identical information most things I have read suggest putting it in one table and then adding a linking table for flexibility. Selecting the items that matched user_id x in the linking table should be very fast, even with a third column for additional filtering permissions.

Also, even if you have a huge single table search, adding indexes to the relevant columns would speed up the search process greatly. The only situation I could think of where #2 might be better is if you locked tables.

I’m not an expert though, so I would like to hear what everyone else thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following table structure

Put

```
    User Id ownership, permissions, location size etc imageFileIndex
```

in one table
and in another table

```
    imageFileIndex vFile
```